Вывод всех элементов словаря при передаче в функцию
При передаче словаря в функцию выводится только первый элемент ключ- значение. Как вывести остальные?
if operation_number == 7: # применение транзакции
    def use_transactions(trans):
        for i in range(len(trans)):
            if sum_transaction > limit_sum:
                print("Транзакция " + name_transaction + " на сумму " + str(int(sum_transaction)) + " руб. не может быть"
                    " применена (превышен лимит).")
            else:
                    print("Транзакция " + name_transaction + " на сумму " + str(sum_transaction) + " руб. успешно применена.")
        return trans
    use_transactions(trans)


Привет. Подскажи, пожалуйста, чем является каждая из переменных? Это называется тайпхинтинг, когда отмечаются типы переменных, чтобы и тебе, и другим было понятно, какого типа переменная и что в ней содержится. Я так понял, trans — это словарь?
P.S. Объявлять функции внутри условий не совсем корректно. Думаю, твоему коду это не нужно явно)

приведите пример вашего trans.

ссылка на полный код https://replit.com/@Sanieklaki/SweetWiltedTransformations#main_BANK_TEST.py

trans - это словарь который принимает данные от пользователя. При передачи словаря в функцию, выводится только первое значение, нужно что бы выводились все значения словаря. Заранее извиняюсь за свой код))

for sum_transaction, name_transaction in trans.items:. Текучая организация словаря может привести к потерям некоторых данных. Первая транзация на 10, вторая транзация на 10 в итоге в словаре будет только одна транзакция вместо двух.

Что-то я не вижу, чтобы вы переменную цикла i как-то использовали, у вас внутри цикла используются переменные, которые вообще никак с циклом не связаны.

def use_transactions(trans):
    for ta_sum in trans:
        if ta_sum > limit_sum:
            print(f"Транзакция {trans[ta_sum]} на сумму {ta_sum} руб. не может быть применена (превышен лимит).")
        else:
            print(f"Транзакция {trans[ta_sum]} на сумму {ta_sum} руб. успешно применена.")


Необходимости дополнительно возвращать словарь транзакций в вашем случае нет.
Функцию лучше всё же вынести за цикл while True, как я и предполагал в комментарии к вопросу.
Кажется, у вас есть проблемы с базовым пониманием концепции циклов. Думаю, стоит дополнительно изучить, как в целом работают циклы на итерируемых объектах. К примеру, вы запускаете цикл по i, но не используете эту переменную в цикле, а вместо этого используете какие-то внешние переменные sum_transaction и name_transaction. И цикл фактически отработал вхолостую.
По-хорошему, если рассматривать бизнес-логику, вам стоит перейти на списки, потому что хранение транзакций в словарях, как отметил Сергей в комментариях, может привести к потере данных, если две транзакции будут на одну и ту же сумму.


ВСЕМ ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!!ВСЁ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ!!!!!!
